# How do I cast a void pointer of large size to different types sequentially

Tags: c

I'm looking to cast my void pointer value to different values one after the other. Would I just add the number of bytes from the last type using the size of function? The test value is just a space in memory I want to use to put these values.

```
void* test;

int* a = (int*)test;
*a = 5;

char*b = (char*)(test+sizeof(int));
*b = 'b';

int* c = (int*)(test+sizeof(int)+sizeof(char))
*c = 6;
```

Comment: What are you ultimately trying to accomplish?  Your question is very unclear, and your example has undefined behavior everywhere (using an uninitialized variable, accessing pointers without proper alignment).  If you want some memory that has an `int` followed by a `char` followed by another `int`, why not use a `struct`?

Comment: Also just remembered: doing math on a `void*` is technically not allowed. Some compilers let you do it but it is non-standard.

Comment: @jamesdlin, the test variable is just empty space of x bytes that was given to me that I want to use. I just don't have it initialized here. The int, char, int is just an example case that I used to see hoe to go about doing this.

Comment: @chonglawr To see how you go about doing what?  Again, what are you ultimately trying to accomplish?

Comment: For all intent and purposes, the chunk of memory you received is just as good as a chunk of memory that `malloc()` allocates. If you already have an idea what data structure it should be, you can use a pointer of that data structure to access the memory locations of this chunk of memory. Let's say `struct data mydata = *test`, then initialize each member, `mydata->a = 5; mydata->b = 'b'; mydata->c = 6`.

Answer (score 2):

This is best done with `char` pointers and `memcpy`. Using `char` pointers allows you to do simple pointer math (and avoids any trouble with the [strict aliasing rule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/98650/what-is-the-strict-aliasing-rule)). Using `memcpy` avoids any issues with alignment.

In the function below, the first argument is a pointer to memory, and the second argument is the size of that memory in chars.

```
void foo( void *test, int size )
{
    if ( size < 2*sizeof(int) + 1 )
        return;           // buffer is not big enough

    char *a = test;                 // int
    char *b = a + sizeof(int);      // char
    char *c = b + 1;                // int

    int value = 5;
    memcpy( a, &value, sizeof(int) );

    *b = 'b';

    value = 6;
    memcpy( c, &value, sizeof(int) );
}
```

To extend this to an arbitrary number of items, I would write the code as shown below. (Note that there is no safety net here, the buffer passed to the function must be big enough to hold all the values.)

```
void bar( void *test )
{
    char *ptr = test;

    int value = 5;
    memcpy( ptr, &value, sizeof(int) );
    ptr += sizeof(int);

    *ptr++ = 'b';

    value = 6;
    memcpy( ptr, &value, sizeof(int) );
    ptr += sizeof(int);

    // ...
}
```

Comment: It should be mentioned that this memory cannot be used directly, stored objects must be copied to an actual variable of a correct type before they can be read.

Comment: @2501 Agreed. The OP never did answer the question, *"what are you ultimately trying to accomplish?"* One possible application is serialization. In which case, you are correct, the variables would need to be deserialized before being used.

Answer (score 1):

This is not what you want to do, I think.

If you want to copy some objects into memory then you should use `memcpy` and a `char *` to some memory buffer. And yes you would move forward `sizeof()` bytes after each `memcpy`.

`char` pointers are used for bytes. `void` pointers are used when the code does not know what the type is, like when passing a user defined callback and data structure into a library.

Creating a thread for example:

```
int pthread_create(pthread_t *thread, const pthread_attr_t *attr,
                   void *(*start_routine) (void *), void *arg);
```